# How to send mail through C# asp.net for contact form

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am trying to create contact form to send email  (`from` and `to` will be from user interface):

```
try {
   MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
   SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
   mail.From = new MailAddress("fromadd");
   mail.To.Add("toadd");
   mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
   mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";
   SmtpServer.Port = 587;
   SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username","password");
   SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

   SmtpServer.Send(mail);
   MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
}
catch (Exception ex) {
   MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

This works for only Gmail - however, I would like to make it work for any email provider - how would I go about this?

Comment: What do you mean `generic code`? The only thing that causes it to be specifically for gmail is the SMTP value and *possibly* the port.

Comment: Why not just pass the Port and Host as parameters to this function?

Comment: it means i have to type From -- yahoo id and to -- gmail id .. generic

Answer (score 2):

You should configure the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k.aspx) in the web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="network">
        <network
          host="localhost"
          port="25"
          defaultCredentials="true"
        />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Then in your code you can do:

```
    try
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("fromadd");
        mail.To.Add("toadd");
        mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
        mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from GMAIL";

        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();            
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your `SmtpClient` configuration in your web.config. This will make it flexible.

http://blog.dotnetclr.com/archive/2009/08/18/511.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Don't use hardcoded parameters for the connection to the smtp-server.

Use the webconfig instead. Your program will be more "generic". Just alter the config when you want to send through another smtp-server

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
    MailMessage msgObj = new MailMessage();

    msgObj.To = "example@example.com";
    msgObj.From = "Mike";
    msgObj.Bcc = "example@example.com";
    msgObj.Subject = "Test Message";
    msgObj.Body = "Hello World!";
    SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "Your Server";
    SmtpMail.Send("FromEmail", "ToEmail", "Subject", "Query");
    SmtpMail.Send(msgObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like the only thing that might be preventing you from sending the email using any email server is the fact that some mail servers require authentication (or possibly an alternative port number).

Here is a bit of basic code that should get you pointed in the right direction

```
public class SendMail
{

    public SendMail(string SMTPServer, string fromEmail)
    {
        this.SMTPServer = SMTPServer;
        this.FromEmail = fromEmail;
    }

    public SendMail(string SMTPServer, string fromEmail, string Username, string Password) : this(SMTPServer, fromEmail)
    {
        this.Username = Username;
        this.Password = Password;
    }

    public string SMTPServer { get; set; }
    public string FromEmail { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public void Send(string toEmail, string subject, string data)
    {
        MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
        mailMsg.To.Add(toEmail);

        MailAddress mailAddress = new MailAddress(this.FromEmail);

        mailMsg.From = mailAddress;

        mailMsg.Subject = subject;
        mailMsg.Body = data;
        mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(this.SMTPServer, 25);

        if (this.Username.Length > 0 && this.Password.Length > 0)
        {
            System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(this.Username, this.Password);
            smtpClient.Credentials = credentials;
        }

        smtpClient.Send(mailMsg);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am trying this code .

```
try
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress("best@technosys.com");
    mail.To.Add("best@technosys.com");
    mail.Subject = "Accept Request";
    mail.Body = body;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
   smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("best@technosys.com", " password");
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtp.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", ex.ToString());
}
```